# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application

Tags: jsf, tomcat, ant, tomcat6

I changed the way an application was being built. It was being built by maven earlier, I changed it to ANT.

After the change, I started getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. 
>       This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you 
>           properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application 
>           and that all the necessary libs are included. 
>       Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for 
>          any exceptions!

If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.

A typical config looks like this:

```jsf
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

```jsf
javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:246)
javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:200)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:112)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The web.xml does not have the following:

```jsf
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

But since the application was working without it earlier, I am thinking this is some other issue. I looked up for this issue in google and most of them suggest it could be because of compatibility issue with Tomcat jar (`servlet-api.jar`, `el-api.jar`, `jsp-api.jar`). I couldn't remove el-api.jar as it is being used by the application.

This seems to be some dependency / libraries issue.

Comment: Extract the Ant-produced WAR file with a ZIP tool and inspect /WEB-INF/lib folder. Does it look all right for a Tomcat-targeted JSF web application? If you have no clue as to library management, then well, list those JARs in the question. The concrete problem at least suggests a messup of JSF API JAR files.

Comment: This is a little too late however wanted to reply so that it can be useful for someone else ! The issue was with conflicts of jars ... there was another servlet-api.jar with a slightly different name that i had not noticed !